# java - How accurate is Runtime.maxMemory - is it OK to see difference of 9gig?

Tags: java, linux, memory, ulimit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Runtime.maxMemory incorrect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463868/java-runtime-maxmemory-incorrect)

I start application with -Xmx100G.  The value returned by Runtime.maxMemory is 91G. Where does the remaining memory (9G) go?

I see from other posts that the API is not 100% accurate. I would like to know more about the difference.

I set the virtual memory size by

```
$ulimit -a 100000000.
```

The command fails.

```
$java -Xmx99g -version 
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```