# How to check the system memory load

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I need to programmatically check the system load.
I understand that there is no general way, and we need as a check on a separate Windows and Ubuntu

Comment: In case someone points out `Runtime.maxMemory()` and `Runtime.totalMemory()`, here's the [obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463868/java-runtime-maxmemory-incorrect) on why they can be incorrect.

Comment: @Vineet - and they only report Heap memory usage from the JVM's perspective, not total memory usage from the system perspective; i.e. they don't report non-heap usage, physical page residency, paging rates, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your aim is to track down a memory leak (apparently), it would be better to use existing tools to monitor memory utilization; e.g.

- Java profiling tools included in the JDK.
- System specific tools such as "top", "vmstat", "iostat" and so on, and their Windows equivalents.

Trying to do this from Java is only going to confuse the issue.

Comment: If you confuse the issue, maybe it will go away?

Comment: @Adriaan Koster - Nice one :-)