# Sun's JVM heap size limit on Ubuntu 64-bit

Tags: java, jvm, heap-size

I see some strange behavior on the maximum heap size I get on Sun's JVM, compared to JRockit.

I'm running IDEA on 64-bit VMs on a 64-bit system (Ubuntu 11.04). The JVM versions I'm testing are: `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)` (which I got with `apt-get install sun-java6-jdk`, and `Oracle JRockit(R) (build R28.1.3-11-141760-1.6.0_24-20110301-1432-linux-x86_64, compiled mode)` (which I downloaded from Oracle's site a couple of months ago).

If I pass the parameters -Xms1g -Xmx3g, IDEA will report a maximum heap size of 1820M on Sun's JVM, and 3072M (as expected) on JRockit.

If I pass -Xms2g -Xmx4g, IDEA will report 3640M on Sun's and 4096M on JRockit.

What is happening? What are those mystic numbers 1820M and 3640M = 2*1820M? Isn't it possible to run Sun's JVM with the exact heap size I want?

EDIT:

An answer has been deleted, so just to bring my comments back: please note that I'm talking about the MAX size, not the current size. Consider that I've researched a lot before asking the question here, so there's no need to teach the meaning of Xms, Xmx or any of the other of the parameters that specify the size of regions of the memory (those can be found elsewhere).

EDIT2:

I wrote the following simple code to test this behavior:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  while (true) {
    final Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    System.out.println("r.freeMemory() = " + r.freeMemory()/1024.0/1024);
    System.out.println("r.totalMemory() = " + r.totalMemory()/1024.0/1024);
    System.out.println("r.maxMemory() = " + r.maxMemory()/1024.0/1024);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

Then I ran it with -Xmx100m, -Xmx110m, -Xmx120m, etc... for many many different values, both on Sun's JVM and o JRockit. Sun's will always report a bizarre value for `maxMemory()` and would grow on big steps (like 30M) between runs. JRockit reported the exact value every time.

Comment: What version of the JVM are you using btw? Just wondering.

Comment: Added to the question, as this might be very relevant information I forgot to give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Xms` and `Xmx` only serve to indicate the minimum and maximum sizes of the allocated heap. The actual size of the allocated heap could/will be a value between the minimum and maximum, as the JVM can resize the heap, especially during object allocation events or garbage collection events.

If you need the JVM to use the "exact" heap size, you can specify `Xms` and `Xmx` values that are close enough to each other, so that heap resizing does not occur. Of course, these values must correspond to a contiguous amount of free memory.

The above section assumed something else, and can be ignored for practical purposes.

Based on the code used to calculate heap size, it should be noted that `Runtime.maxMemory()` [returns a value that does not correspond to the value passed in the Xmx flag](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4686462) for the Hotspot JVM; the documentation is vague in stating that it will simply return a value that indicates [the memory available for the JVM to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463868/java-runtime-maxmemory-incorrect/1463878#1463878).

Inferring from your posted code's behavior, heap resizing will result in different values being reported for different invocations of `Runtime.maxMemory()`. Also, it would be needless to point out that the JRockit JVM reports the value passed in via `Xmx` flag.

Comment: maybe you misread my question, or I didn't express myself correctly. I'm not talking about the use of heap not being the exact values specified. I'm saying the the max heap available, reported by the JVM, is not the value I specified, in the case of Sun's JVM. It is the correct value on JRockit. Obviously, the actual heap usage will vary in time and will be between Xms and Xmx. What I'm talking about is Sun not recognizing the correct value for Xmx and using multiple of 1820 instead.

Comment: How are you getting the max heap size? I suppose IDEA is reporting the current and not the max heap size.

Comment: No, Vineet. IDEA reports both the current and the max heap size. I'm talking about the max heap size. The current looks correct to me (keeps growing, growing, and then shrinks on a garbage collection). Consider that I've research a lot before asking the question here.

Comment: Does it mean that Sun is actually ignoring the Xmx parameter?

Comment: No, it means that you should not be using Runtime.maxMemory to read the value of `Xmx`. They are two different things for HotSpot.